# Automatically testing all parts of a new computer

Tags: computer-building

What would be the best way to run tests on all parts of a new computer after first putting it together?

I'd want to test the RAM, the CPU and the hard disks. (I assume there's nothing else worth testing)

The best thing would be to run something that would automatically do tests on all those parts and give a report at the end so you could easily see if there are any dodgy parts that need to be sent back and replaced.

Is there a program that achieves what I want already? Maybe even a live CD?

Or do I need to pick the tools I want to use and somehow automate them? MemTest for the RAM, manufacturer's tool for the hard disk etc?

Comment: > I assume their's nothing else worth testing

Don't forget power supply, optical drives, video card, and network card.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What programs can I use to test my computer's hardware?](http://superuser.com/questions/351617/what-programs-can-i-use-to-testmy-computers-hardware)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a few ideas:

- [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) is good for testing the RAM (run it non-stop for more than 24 hours; we usually do 72 before declaring the RAM 'good').
- You can beat the CPU up for a few days using [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/) as well.
- If you've got cash to spend, check out [Ultra-X's Quick Tech Pro](http://www.uxd.com/qtpro.shtml) software.

Comment: Prime95 will catch most issues with memory and processors.  If you can pass a 24 hour blend test without over heating you are probably good, and a lot of people don't even go that long.  Memtest86+ is good when you fail Prime95 and are trying to narrow down the specific cause of the failure, RAM or processor, and also which specific stick of RAM and/or which slot is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try bruning a Linux CD of some sort, Ubuntu perhaps. Most Linux distributions have pretty advanced tools to test RAM (**memtest86+**), drives (**palimpsest**, others) and networking (various). As for CPU, I think it's more of a clear-cut "it works or it doesn't" situation.

I don't think there's anything that goes and does all those things for you and puts the results in a nice little box, etc. But unless you're making computers on a large scale, it shouldn't hurt too much to look at each monitoring program in turn.